# Why is Excel reporting (on the status bar) that it is calculating when I have no formula in my spreadsheet?

Tags: excel

I have a plain file where I do modifications and I am seeing that Excel is reporting that is calculation (and it indicates the CPU consumption) every time when I paste something in that spreadsheet?

Edit: I should add that this file is created via Python. If I open up Excel and I I paste the same in an empty spreadsheet no calculation is happening

Update: this can be avoided by disabling automatic formula calculation but again I have no formula there

Comment: Are there any hidden tabs? Or any "Very Hidden" tabs that might contain formulas? You can see "Very Hidden" tabs by going to the VBE (Alt+F11) and looking for tabs in the "Project" pane for that workbook. If you see a tab listed there that isn't on the front end of excel then you can unhide it by clicking on it, going to the "Properties" pane and changing the "Visible" property to "xlSheetVisible".

Comment: No there are no hidden tabs